# Mysql : how to retrieve a list of row where one field doesn't contain a specific value from an ENUM

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have a table which lists users albums.

PRIMARY KEY, USER KEY, TYPE and TITLE.

The TYPE field is an ENUM.

Normally every user has an entry of type 'avatar' created automatically upon registration but it seems one hasn't.

I want a query that can output the users key which don't have any 'avatar' type entry associated.

I thought this query would do the trick :

```
   SELECT * FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT user_key FROM `album` WHERE 1
   ) a
   OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT  user_key FROM `album` WHERE type = 'avatar'
   ) b
   ON a.user_key = b.user_key
```

The goal is to select every distinct user from the table, then every user which has an 'avatar' entry and finally to do an outer join in order to retrieve only the users which don't have that entry.

With an inner join I get the right user list that have this entry (which doesn't solve my problem) but with an outer join I get a syntax error.

Did I get something wrong with outer joins or is there a smarter way to get what I want ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "OUTER JOIN" in MySQL ! , you should use "LEFT | RIGHT JOIN", and for a full outer join you can UNION them like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.user_key = b.user_key
UNION
SELECT * FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.user_key = b.user_key
```

but it seems no need to joining selects !, If you want to get the list of users who have not 'avatar' in type field, you shoud do like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_Key) FROM albums WHERE Type <> 'avatar'
AND user_key NOT IN (Select DISTINCT(user_key) FROM albums WHERE Type = 'avatar');
```

There is No need to use "NOT IN" for ENUM type because ENUM type gets only one value and SET type gets some values

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've never had to use outer JOIN in mysql before.
I don't understand the use of LEFT JOIN in that case since I want to join two subrequest from the same table.

If I just use UNION without the left joins I get the opposite result (user having an avatar album). As I mentioned to Moe if I select types that are not avatar I will get all the rows of other types. What I want is the users that doesn't have any rows associated with them containing 'avatar' type, even though they can have other types associated.

Comment: Awesome, that works. I didn't think about this type of subrequest to remove users having an avatar entry, very clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the qurstion correctly, you just want the user_key column for all users whos type is not 'avatar'

```
SELECT DISTINCT(user_key) FROM album WHERE type IS NOT IN ('avatar')
```

Comment: Not exactly, since there is other types if I try NOT IN I will get the other types but anyway I don't know why but that query gives me an error as well when only "IN" works properly.
I should precise that I'm using MariaDB but I don't think there is such a difference between these two.

Comment: So you want to get all the user keys for people who do have avatars and subtract those from the list of distinct user keys

`SELECT DISTINCT user_key FROM album WHERE type NOT IN (SELECT user_key FROM album WHERE type IN ('avatar'))`

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted, Mahmood_M gave me the answer. Your request is trying to withdraw entries whose type is the result of a subrequest retrieving user_key so that doesn't work but I understand the logic I should use to get my result. Thanks !